# Is specifying link dependency required when one static lib is dependent on another static lib?

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries, qmake

General question can be formulated as - if static library lib1 is dependent on another static library lib2, do I need to specify lib2 as linker dependency for lib1, or linking dependencies only need to be specified when libraries are linked against some application (and then every application using lib2 should link against lib1 as well)?

Specifically, I have bunch of static libs and applications, with some dependencies between them, like that:

makeall.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG += ordered
SUBDIRS = coreLib \
    anotherLib \
    ....
    someApp

anotherLib.depends = coreLib 
someApp.depends = coreLib anotherLib
```

coreLib.pro

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib
TARGET = coreLib
#... some .cpp and .h
```

anotherLib.pro

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib
INCLUDEPATH += PATH_TO_CORE_LIB_INCLUDES
DEPENDPATH += PATH_TO_CORE_LIB_INCLUDES
TARGET = anotherLib
```

**#Lines in Question**

someApp.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
DESTDIR = ..\bin
INCLUDEPATH += PATH_TO_CORE_LIB_INCLUDES PATH_TO_ANOTHER_LIB_INCLUDES
DEPENDPATH += PATH_TO_CORE_LIB_INCLUDES PATH_TO_ANOTHER_LIB_INCLUDES
```

**#Lines in question**

What should I use for **Lines in question**:

---

anotherLib.pro

```
(nothing required)
```

someApp.pro

```
PRE_TARGETDEPS += ../bin/coreLib.lib ../bin/anotherLib.lib
```

**OR:**

---

II. anotherLib.pro

```
PRE_TARGETDEPS += ../bin/coreLib.lib
```

someApp

```
PRE_TARGETDEPS += ../bin/anotherLib.lib
```

**OR**

---

III. anotherLib.pro

```
PRE_TARGETDEPS += ../bin/coreLib.lib
```

someApp.pro

```
PRE_TARGETDEPS += ../bin/coreLib.lib ../bin/anotherLib.lib
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building a static library you do not need to link in other static libraries.

When building an executable, you need to include all libraries your code and libraries your code depends on.  The libraries usually need to be in the right order.  If lib foo depends on lib c, then you must use -lfoo -lc.

In the distant past the order of object files within a static library was important, but no more.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! If libraries are in wrong order - it simply won't link, right?

Comment: You will get undefined symbols, even if the symbols are defined in a library.

Comment: including your library names or path between --start-group and --end-group will cause your linker to continuously look your libraries until all the dependencies are resolved.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to find out is to try compiling your application and look for compilation errors provided you have included all the external libraries you have used. **Compiler is your best friend.**

Comment: It compiles in any of the three configurations I stated. I'm concerned about 2 things - 1. not to add extra dependencies. 2. Ensure whole project builds properly when soem of the libraries are modified.

Comment: you don't have to worry about extra dependencies if the symbols in one of your libraries is not used it's automatically discarded by your compiler or not looked into at all check the manual of your compiler for this. also to manage dependencies between libraries include all of them that is the ones your program depends on directly and the ones your libraries depend on between --start-group and --end-group for more info check `ld` man page.